# Testing successful login with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to go through Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial, but it's my third time through the thing and now I'm trying to implement Devise instead of the home rolled authentication in the tutorial. As you can imagine, this is a little bit painful, mainly due to the test driven development in the RoR tutorial not mixing well with Devise. My current hang up is that I can't seem to successfully test a successful login. I have the website up on localhost, so I know the login works, but my test is still failing for some reason. Here's the integration test snippet

```
def setup
  @user = users(:michael)
end

...

test "login with valid information" do
  get user_session_path
  assert_equal 200, status
  post user_session_path, 'user[email]' => @user.email, 'user[password]' => "password" 
  follow_redirect!
  assert_equal 200, status
  assert_select "a[href=?]", user_session_path, count: 0 # THIS LINE FAILS
  assert_select "a[href=?]", destroy_user_session_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
end
```

The error I get is

```
FAIL["test_login_with_valid_information", UsersLoginTest, 2016-06-19 11:06:18 -0400]
test_login_with_valid_information#UsersLoginTest (1466348778.61s)
      Expected exactly 0 elements matching "a[href="/users/sign_in"]", found 1..
      Expected: 0
        Actual: 1
```

The login bar up at the top switches from `Sign in` to `Account`, so it looks like the test isn't getting the user in the setup block successfully signed in. Another, possibly unrelated, issue is that in another test I have, I try the same exact login method with `post user_session_path...` and then check that `current_user` is not null with `assert_not current_user.nil?`, but I get the error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for #<UsersLoginTest:0x00557f81155648>
```

I've looked around and made sure that I have the correct lines of `devise_for :users` in my routes.rb file. I'm pretty sure It's not able to access `current_user` because somehow I don't have my integration test able to access resources in Devise. Those are my two problems! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I tried

```
post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[email]' => @user.email, 'user[password]' => @user.password
```

instead of the previous method of testing the login, but I get the following errors

```
ERROR["test_login_with_valid_information", UsersLoginTest, 2016-06-28 20:40:59 -0400]
 test_login_with_valid_information#UsersLoginTest (1467160859.16s)
RuntimeError:         RuntimeError: not a redirect! 200 OK
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

ERROR["test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout", UsersLoginTest, 2016-06-28 20:40:59 -0400]
 test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout#UsersLoginTest (1467160859.18s)
NameError:         NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<UsersLoginTest:0x0055d0b9e0df50>
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:49:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:49:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

Edit 2:

I used Jemima's suggested fixture and reran the tests. Upon checking in the test log, I found

```
-------------------------------------------------
UsersLoginTest: test_login_with_valid_information
-------------------------------------------------
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 762146111]]
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-01 18:46:41 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-01 18:46:41 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"michael@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"michael@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
```

So it looks like it's unauthorized? Also, I attempted to put `include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers` at the top of my user login test, but it just throws the error `NameError: uninitialized constant Devise::Test`.

Comment: Just in case, did you read that [article](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29) referenced below? One of the thing there is '''Every time you want to unit test a devise controller, you need to tell Devise which mapping to use. We need that because ActionController::TestCase and spec/controllers bypass the router'', so it seems your references to route.rb won't work for tests

Comment: As for `current_user` helper, it's added to ApplicationController by Devise gem. It won't be available to your tests then by default. See [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb) - ``For controller tests, please include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` instead.``

Comment: Finally, you should investigate deeply in what causes your problem. Having a sign_in link remaining in the output is not helping here. You should find a way to debug what's happening on your post and what's failing, e.g. some Devise error.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @imarg, I haven't gotten around to testing out all of what Jemima included in their answer, but I would start there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My test.log is not as detailed as yours, so I was wondering if there is an option somewhere or if you use some gem to make it have more detail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue that might help you to the answer. I believe my fixture isn't correct and therefore Devise is not authenticating.

My user fixture, in case it helps you:

```
user_no_club:
  email: noclub@example.com
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>
  confirmed_at: 2016-01-02 08:31:23
  confirmation_sent_at: 2016-01-02 08:30:59
```

And log/test.log shows the correct email is getting passed, but then:

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

EDIT:

On further investigation, I think Devise integration testing should be done with the [Devise helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#integration-tests). I've not been able to get it working, but my understanding from the [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-devise/_efNO8hQa0E) is that the docs and gem might be temporarily out of sync.

Edit following further comments about testing in units and controllers:

I'm using sign_in @user in unit tests and controllers and that's working fine. Controller test such as the following is working well:

```
@user = users(:one)
@other_user = users(:two)
sign_in @user
get :edit, id: @other_user
assert_redirected_to root_url
```

Comment: Although this didn't really solve my problem, I think it provided the best answer. Have you gotten the functionality of using resources from the devise gem in your unit tests? I think I can do a functionally similar test by checking if `sign_in @user` works, but devise resources like `sign_in` and `current_user` are not currently available from my unit test.

Comment: In my case I was missing   `confirmed_at` row from the fixture. Thanks for posting the code.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried it with a post_via_redirect?

```
post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[email]' => @user.email, 'user[password]' => @user.password
```

Edit:
Have you included the Devise test helpers to your test_helper?

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

Comment: I have, but it did not seem to work either. I will retry later today and update with specific results using your snippet.

Comment: Did you include Devise::TestHelpers within the ActionController::TestCase?